# Access object in nested array in Meteor templates

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have users table whose structure is as below for a single document

```
{
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "new user",
        "gender" : ""
    },
    "followers" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "yQLrjsbAnKHW7Zoef",
            "name" : "vid vid"
        },
        {
            "id" : "bGLrjsbAnKHW7Zoef",
            "name" : "sid sid"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my helper function is

```
Template.followers.helpers({
    followers: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()},{_id:0,followers:1, profile:1});
    }
});
```

now I want to display data of just followers as :

```
name: Vid
name: Sid
```

Basically I want to access the elements in followers array in my template.
Currently it's

```
{{#each followers}}
      {{ profile.name}}
      {{ followers}} 
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

The problem is that `Meteor.users.find()` returns only limited fields. Firstly I tried using field specifiers in the method where `users` is published but that didn't work. So following is what I did:

In server side, declared new variable as:

```
UserProfiles : = Meteor.users;
```

Added new publish method where i specified fields I required as: 
enter code here

```
Meteor.publish('UserProfiles', function () {
    return UserProfiles.find({},{
    fields : {
        'followers' : 1,
        'profile'   : 1,
        'createdAt' : 1
    }
});
```

});

Added following line in client side:

```
UserProfiles : = Meteor.users; 
Meteor.subscribe("UserProfiles");
```

Then in my files I fired a query and returned as:

```
users: function (){ 
    return UserProfiles.find(selector, {
       fields : {
           'followers' : 1,
            'profile'   : 1,
            'createdAt' : 1
       }
    });
}
```

Inside template code:

```
{{#each users}}
     Follower of {{profile.name}}
     {{#each followers}}
          {{> follower}}
     {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is your template code**

```
{{#each followers}} {{ profile.name}} {{ followers}} {{/each}}
```

**Correct template code**

```
{{#each followers}} 
  {{profile.name}} 
  {{#each this.followers}}
    {{name}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

This will give you the name of the profile holder and the followers for that profile.

Comment: Its not working. It just gives me first followers details which is 'vid vid'.

Comment: It's working for me, gives me list of all the people and their followers.

Comment: Did you change anything in helper?

Comment: It just gives me vid vid and thats all!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @DarpanKakadia